# Counting The Total Records From Table in Pagination Mode

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project with a table (figure A) and display all the records to the web browser with pagination something like this:

[image]

How can I do so that the cumulative each page of the 'Amount' counted correctly in the last page?

I've try by looping but it give me result in page 1 = 21, page 2 = 24, and so on. Of course this is wrong.

Need help. Thank You

Comment: Is your question on counting total num of records or total amount? it is not clear

Comment: Total amount (cumulative page1, page2, page3, and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate query for the total amount:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM tablename
```

Then display it in the end of the pages, outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank for your solution Mahomoud, I think this is a quick and simple solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well MySQL WITH ROLLUP is used for this. This adds an extra row at last and can be used with aggregate functions.

```
SELECT
  id,
  IFNULL(stock,'Total') AS `stock`,
  SUM(amount) AS Total
FROM board
GROUP BY stock WITH ROLLUP
```

You can add limit in this query according to your requirements

### SQL Fiddle Example

With Limit

### SQL Fiddle Example